# Why do I need react context, createContext, useContext, useStore in Mobx

Tags: typescript, mobx, mobx-react

I am using Mobx for persistance in my Typescript app and I have my own singleton class for the store:

```
export class MyStore {
    @observable something;
    @observable somethingElse;
}

export myStore:MyStore = new MyStore();
```

This is in a file "data/store/MyStore". So in all my components, why can't I just do this:

```
import { myStore } from "data/store/MyStore";
```

Can't I just import myStore and use it?

Why do I have to go through all the troble os using createContext and useStore to get the store? I can just get it by importing it. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. It is totally fine to use this approach with singleton stores.

`Context`, `Provider`, `inject` and other stuff is used mostly for testing purposes (because it is easier to mock stores, `Provider` works like some sort of Dependency Injection thing) or for server side rendering. If you don't need any of those then you can just skip it altogether.